# Pros and cons of Cinelerra vs Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: video-editor

What are the pros and cons of Cinelerra over Adobe Premiere Pro CS 6? And could you provide a link of the source?

Comment: This is not a question about a problem. It is not specific to Ubuntu.  Pros and cons can be a matter of opinion rather then being specific and helpful. Try both and draw your own conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience of Cinelerra is that it's an old fashioned clunky NLE from a previous age which is somewhat buggy.  That said, it has some advanced features, and does seem to have kept up with the plethora of newer HD video formats.  It's a little hard to get working the way you want.  If you do use it, you'll want to use the "community version".

You should give serious consideration also to Blender which apart from its use in 3D modelling has also a rather capable non-linear video editor as well (VSE).

Answer (score 1):

1. Cinerella is free software. You can try it for free and if you don't like it, it costs you nothing.
2. Cinerella is maintained by updates. A new version of Cinerella for Ubuntu for 2014 is coming soon. If you buy Adobe Premiere Pro CS6, within a few years the latest version of Cinerella will be better than the version of Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 that you bought.
3. Cinelerra-CV (the community version) packages for Ubuntu are available from the ["Cinelerra-CV" team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Instructions for adding this PPA to your system can be found at the same link.

<sup>**Source:** [Cinerella official website](http://cinelerra.org/1/)</sup>